# 1st program, return true if List 1 has more elements than List 2

Tags: prolog

This is my first program in prolog, I've been reading about it and just don't seem to grasp a couple core concepts(I think).  I'm trying to write a functor that will take two lists and return true only if the first list has more elements.  I've gotten a few simple programs to work, but I have hit a roadblock here.  I'm trying to call size inside of isLonger and set temp variables to the return of size.  This seems like a bad(and incorrect) way of going about this in prolog.  I'm getting a:

`ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

```
% List 1

a([cat, dog, horse]).
b([1, 2, 3, 4]).
c([x, [a, b], y, z]).
c([red, yellow, green, blue]).


% isLonger function
isLonger([],[]).
isLonger(L1,L2) :-  A = size(L1,N), B = size(L2,N), A > B.

 % size([],N).
size([_|T],N) :- size(T,N1), N is N1+1.
```

Input:

`isLonger([x,y,z], [7,8,9,10]).`

Comment: In prolog there are predicates, not functions. You can't get the size by doing `A = size(L1,N)`. That expression attempts to instantiate `A` to match `size(L1,N)`. It doesn't execute `size` as a function and return a value. The `size` predicate never instantiates `N`, so the comparison `>` occurs with uninstantiated variables, which gives the error. Also, there's a built-in predicate `length` you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list `L1` is longer than `L2` if `L1` is not empty and `L2` is empty; or if the tail of `L1` is longer than the tail of `L2`.

```
longer([_|_], []).
longer([_|T1], [_|T2]) :- longer(T1, T2).
```

Unfortunately, that solution would leave lost of choice points behind on several Prologs which can index predicates on the first argument only. That can be solved just reversing the argument order:

```
longer(L1, L2) :- shorter(L2, L1).
shorter([], [_|_]).
shorter([_|T1], [_|T2]) :- shorter(T1, T2)
```